# Time on mock GPS location in emulator not correct

Tags: android, gps, emulation

When I run my app in the emulator, I get a GPS location but I have noticed that the time attached to the location appears to always be fixed and is not synchronized to either the OS clock or any other clock for that matter. This is bad because my app uses the time of the location as part of its processing. Is there a way to correct this? If not, is there a way my code can tell it's running in the emulator and I'll modify the time of the GPS setting when it gets recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Change your app to not synchronize on Location time, sync on System time instead.
Otherwise your app (or parts) might fail in test mode, simulations, unit tests.

> Is there a way my code can tell it's running in the emulator

I think the altitude is always 0 in emulator.